Why are watched tags and ignored tags missing from the main page?
It used to be the case that, on the main page at https://stackoverflow.com, I could view various categories of questions, set up watched/ignored tags, and search for such questions.
Now all I can see is "interesting posts", with no way to sort/categorize the results.

Now "interesting posts" sounds nice, but only about 5 % of what I see there can actually be described as such. Why are core features of a Q&A site (is it anymore even?) missing from the main page?
Sure, I can navigate to https://stackoverflow.com/questions (which I guessed from other URLs, since there are no visible links or buttons on the main page that would lead me there), but that simply means the redesign of the main page has failed ‒ I need to go to another page as the "main" one to actually use the site. However, I fear even /questions is going to be abridged eventually, since redesign for redesign's sake at the expense of features is far too common.

As I understood this is not a duplicate of the other question which is directly linked to the widgets, this one is also talking about the Home page which is the exactly the same complaint I have. Since the redesign I can't see the questions with my tags Highlighted and the so called "Interesting for you" are not interesting at all. This is actually discouraging me from helping the community, it became a lot harder to find question that I can actually help with.

@JorgeCampos there's another question that reports the missing highlight on watched tags. If that's what OP wanted to ask this would be a duplicate of that.

Thanks @AbdulAzizBarkat They should probably have marked as duplicated of that then! :) I've added a comment there and upvoted.

This question is similar to: Questions with watched tags are no longer highlighted on home page after redesign. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Because the powers that be, in their infinite wisdom, decided that reminding me of my own name was more important than having something useful there.

i think that's somewhat of a poor dupe, the primary issue you seem to be outlining is the missing watched tags widget, which is missing because your browser size is too small such that it got yeeted from the list of three widgets up top. this is by (poor) design but they're working on a solution. there's also the missing filters... but.. that too is by design, the new design did away with any form of filtering (including the custom filters widget that used to be on the right column)

@KevinB it used to be closed for the primary reason. I guess it was reopened because it mentions two different problem and the first dupe doesn't cover both. OP seems to prefer it be closed against the other ¯\(ツ)/¯ It shouldn't have been reopened at all but this is where we are right now.

Kevin B is correct in this comment. This was due to browser window size. Those widgets are now responsive and should all be displayed at all browser widths.
In particular, the tags widget now drops below the others like this:


Is there any concern for the amount of vertical space this now takes up on mobile? Especially given that the widgets can't be collapsed or shrunk; questions are now completely out of frame for me on homepage load: https://i.sstatic.net/Da2ZIKV4.png

@zcoop98 Yes, we've been looking at a carousel idea for the mobile view, which takes up much less vertical space. More on that to come soon!
